# How to fetch sum of column in MySQL using PHP based on id and display it in Android using Volley

Tags: java, php, android

I have a table called hotel_review in this I have hotel_stars column and I want to display the sum of all the hotel stars in Android using Volley. I want to display the average of the hotel rating, to do this I need the sum of the column. I think I'm close but not getting the values. I'm not getting any error but I can not fetch the values as well.

my php code:

```
    <?php
require "init.php";

header('Content-Type: application/json;charset:UTF-8');

$hotel_id = $_POST['hotel_id'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(hotel_stars) AS 'Total' FROM hotel_review WHERE hotel_id = '".$hotel_id."';");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$sum = $row['Total'];

if($query)
{
   $code = "getvalue";
   $data[]['Total'] = $sum;
   $result = array("code"=>$code,"stars" => $data);
   echo json_encode($result);

}else {

    $code = "not_get";
    $msg = "Try Again....";
    array_push($response, array("code"=>$code,"msg"=>$msg));
     //echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset:UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($response);
     // echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

my android code:

```
public void getHotelStars()
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getStars,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("response", response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                        try {
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                            if (code.equals("not_get")) {
                                Toast.makeText(hotel_reviews.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {
                                String totalStars = jsonObject.getString("stars");
//                                String totalCount = jsonObject.getString("total_stars");
                                Toast.makeText(hotel_reviews.this, ""+totalStars, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(hotel_reviews.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("hotel_id",HotelId);
                //params.put("division",EmployeeDivision);
                return params;
            }
        };MySingleton.getInstance(hotel_reviews.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
    }
```

Im getting the proper hotel_id in params.put so no error is there in fetching id.

Comment: What is the response you are getting from server? Did you check this with Postman?

Comment: im getting nothing

Comment: Do one thing that after executing the query please check if it was successful or there was some problem in it. and also check if the query is returning anything if it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this after you fire your query:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $sum=$row["Total"];
    echo $sum;
}
```

after your query and see if your total is there in $sum. Thereafter you can start using that anywhere.

Comment: everythingelse seems to be ok?

Comment: @RajBedi I am just pointing out how you can get the total immediately from your query. Logic of other code looks Ok but you have to try it now. Minor mistakes escape attention of all programmers when working on a project.